# Angular2: Handling multiple possible containers for a Component based on Component variables

Tags: user-interface, architecture, angular

In transitioning/considering angular2 as a replacement for my own self built user interface framework. I'm still stuck on some issues.

One of the issues is **components needing to switch between containers** and having **a lot of possible containers for a component** based on **component variables that might change over time**.

Let's say we have a monthly calendar, on the top we have locations and on the left we have days.

And let's say we have 30 days and 50'ish locations, all need to be shown at once (some of it is behind scrollbars).

This gives us 1500 cells.

Activities have a date and a location and should be rendered inside one of these cells based on their date and location.

1. **How to, in Angular2, render +- 600 activities inside the correct containers on initial render**?
2. **How to, in Angular2, correctly rerender (or remove/add) activities when their location or date changes (either by actions taken in the interface or the server pinging the interface that an activity has changed location or date)**?

I understand how to do this in simple lists of components and I've spent around 30 hours on learning angular2 and observables.

But I'm still not sure how to implement this correctly in angular2.

I'm sure my brain is just hung up on old ways of doing things and I feel I'm in need of a spark to get things going again.

PS: In my own framework it's the component that decides who it's parent/container will be, that makes these (1, 2) questions trivial. But my own framework has it's own issues (and; only 1 maintainer, no good training resources, not built by an army of developers, no sanity checks).

**update**

In code it might look a little like this;

1. calculate current month
2. get list of days in month
3. get activities from db based on current month
4. get locations from db
5. make a table that has locations for columns and days for rows, each cell in the table might be an Angular2 component that has/represents a date and a location
6. assign activities to the correct Angular2 date/location cell component
7. listen to changes in the database via a stream
8. if an activity changed location or date, re-assign the activity to the correct date/location cell component

**I'm stuck on 6 and 8**

Comment: I can't see what the question is about.

Comment: What about adding some actual code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish to make this abstract description easier to understand?

Comment: So what's the problem with this. What is the correct container?

Comment: Hi Günter, I updated the question with a little breakdown of steps, hope this helps, thank you for your interest in my query thusfar.

Comment: You don't actually expect to provide a solution for this question. StackOverflow is not a "give me some code" site or some service for outsourcing development. Your question should contain the code that demonstrates what you've tried, where you failed, error message, ...

Comment: I don't require code as an answer. I'm wondering how one would generally (correctly) approach such a problem in Angular2 on an architectural level.

Comment: Allright Günter, I'll try to include the things I've tried so far to solve this in a semi functioning way and re-ask the question. It will be quite a lot of code to include in here. I'll do my best to keep it succinct. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I think this is way to broad for StackOverflow and architectural questions tend to be opinionated anyway which is also discouraged on SO. You would need to provide way more details for anyone to make suggestions.

Comment: What you likely want to learn about are Smart/Dumb components http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/ and Component Communication https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.